# How to insert data into a table with a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm currently having issues with inserting values into a database table that uses a foreign key from another table to align the is together.  The tables are pretty simple.  One holds information about a project, and the other hold values for the project images.  Here they are in detail.

The `projects` table

```
project_id int(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
project_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
project_permitted timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT "The date that the project took place.",
project_in varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The place where the project took place (ie the city and state).',
project_type varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The project type (ie residentual, commercial, etc).',
project_description longtext,
project_published timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Here is the second table called `project_images`

```
image_id int(50) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
project_id int(50),
image_url varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_projects FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES projects(project_id)
```

What I am trying to do is insert values into the second table using the project_id from the projects table using a subquery.  That query looks like this:

```
insert into project_images (project_id, project_url, project_description) 
values (
(select project_id from projects where project_name = 'The Venue'),
"images/theVenue.png",
"The Venue: an appartment complex in Austin, Texas."
)
```

With this query I keep getting an error that says

> something to the effect of "You are missing a comma or closing bracket
>   near project_id.

Can anyone help or point out the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: Use single quotes `'` instead of double `"`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your query to be like

```
insert into project_images (project_id, project_url, project_description) 
select project_id ,
"images/theVenue.png",
"The Venue: an appartment complex in Austin, Texas."
from projects where project_name = 'The Venue';
```

Comment: Ok thank you.  Im new at this, I will do this from now on

Comment: @kaley36, consider accepting the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this question a bit more, it seems that you cannot use a subquery the way I am using it to get the value of a column,  However, the column can be inserted directly so long as the foreign key points to a primary key from another table that has already be inserted.  The whole point to using this query was for a PHP project, so I guess I'll just do a select query in a project to get its ID then add that to the sql that queries the project_images table.  This seems to be the only way to do that.